# How do I programmatically delete row 0 of UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have an app that has a table view.  Every minute or so I want the first row of the UITableView to disappear.  It would be nice to have it animate off.  I am assuming I need to use something like this:

```
let myNSIndexPath = [NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)]
mainTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(myNSIndexPath, withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

This doesn't work.  I'm not sure exactly how to use IndexPath correctly. My table only has one section and I always want the cell at Index 0 to be removed.  What must to do to get this working correctly?

Comment: you need to delete data from source too and need to reload cell

Comment: delete data for that cell from data source also .

Comment: `data.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)` and `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What actually happens with your posted code?

Answer (score 4):

**One way**

Use **removeAtIndex**

```
yourarray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

And don't forget to reload the table view

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

**Second Way**

```
yourIndexPath = [NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)]
yourtable.beginUpdates() //if you are performing more than one operation use this 
yourarray.removeObjectAtIndex(myNSIndexPath.row)
yourtable.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: yourIndexPath), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
yourtable.endUpdates() //if you are performing more than one operation use this
```

Took help from

- @Rmaddy
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/

Comment: No, do not call `reloadData`. The call to `deleteRowsAtIndexPath` should be used after updating the data source.

Comment: You don't need the calls to `begin/endUpdates`.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the first cell like this.

**One way**

```
   let myNSIndexPath = [NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)]

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.arrayData.removeObjectAtIndex(myNSIndexPath.row) // also remove an array object if exists.
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: myNSIndexPath), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

**Second way**

```
yourArr.removeAtIndex(0)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: No it necessary because it reload that particular cell rather then all cell.

Comment: You can call `deleteRowsAtIndexPath` without calling `begin/endUpdates`. Try it.

Comment: I try it multiple times but some time it does not delete that cell. @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

in SWIFT 4

You can delete the row like this.

```
    let indexPathRow=sender.tag
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPathRow, section: 0)
    arrayList.remove(at: indexPathRow)
    mainTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```